# Is it possible to dummy/fake types with mypy for problematic imports?

Tags: python, python-import, typing

### Motivation:

I have to use external python library ("SDK") which is just a directory of code (i.e. it's not a package and can't be "installed" in any meaninful way).
So the only way to use it is to add it to system path (`sys.path` in python or `PYTHONPATH` in shell) manually.
Also, because its designed for an embedded device, it mostly doesn't work on normal devel workstation (i.e. my laptop) - that is, some things can be imported, some can't.
Also it's not type annotated in any way.

### What I want

So I want to have *some* typing added to my code which calls / uses classes from this library. For example:

```
from bad_evil_library import BadEvilClass # <- fails
...
def myfunc1(x: BadEvilClass) -> str:  # <- not checked
    ...
def myfunc2() -> BadEvilClass:  # <- not checked
    ....
x = myfunc1(myfunc2()) # <- not checked
...
```

Which means even though this function is not called, pytest stops on broken import (yes, I know I can use `--continue-on-collection-errors`), and mypy complains.

So I was thinking - is there some way to make "a dummy type" - i.e. a type which would in fact not represent the real type, but which would still be checked in "my code". Perhaps something like this:

```
BadEvilClass = DummyType()
...
def myfunc1(x: BadEvilClass) -> str:  # <- checked!
    ...
def myfunc2() -> BadEvilClass:  # <- checked!
    ....
x = myfunc1(myfunc2()) # <- checked!
...
```

This would be fine, but it won't be checked against the actual library if is available (so I won't be able to detect that `BadEvilClass` has been renamed, or it lost some method, etc).

### What I don't want

I don't want, don't need and am not supposed to solve the problem of importing - that's NOT the issue and it won't help me in any meaningful way.

I'm not looking for ways to "modify" the "SDK" to make it proper python package or how to import it more easily.

In other words: the problem with importing is not what I want to solve, its only a trigger to the real problem, which is: "How to add at least some typing to untyped external classes so I can at least check if they get passed correctly".

### What have I tried?

Currently, I created "dummy" types, which are all just `Any` and I moved all imports into one function returning a structure containing these "dummy" types, like this:

```
BadEvilClass = Any
WrongCruelClass = Any

@dataclass
class MyInterface:
    bad_evil: BadEvilClass
    wrong_cruel: WrongCruelClass

def get_my_interface() -> MyInterface:
    # setup sys.path..
    from bad_evil_library import BadEvilClass
    from bad_evil_library import WrongCruelClass
    return MyInterface(BadEvilClass(), WrongCruelClass())
```

Which works (there are MORE than one "bad evil class"), but I have absolutely no type checking, so mistakes like this are considered fine:

```
def foo(x: BadEvilClass) -> None:
    ...

my_iface = get_my_interface()
foo(my_iface) # <- I'm passing MyIface, not BadEvilClass!
              # and it passes, since BadEvilClass is really "Any"
```

This is basically the main reason for this question - I want to be able to check if I'm passing the correct types.

### Simplified question:

Is there a way to "partialy" type something which sometimes isn't available, so if it is, I get full typing checks advantage, and if it isn't, I get at least checks in my code?

Comment: When you say "it's not a package", do you mean it's not a *distribution* package that you can install (easily) using `pip`? I think the real question you should be focusing on is "how do I *create* a package from the files in the directory", because it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @chepner the "library" is a bunch of code with embeded dlls and some specific libraried (like numpy) - also it's something which we wil get upgrades on, so if we somehow managed to make a pip package from it, we would have to do it again everytime we received an upgrade. Besides, my most pressing problem is that it just CAN'T be imported on some machines (mostly because of built-in specific version of some standard libraries like numpy)

Comment: "we would have to do it again every time". It's not an *exciting* option, but... it's an option. Whether or not you can use a particular piece seems more like a packaging problem as well, rather than an importing problem. (If you can't use it, it doesn't need to be copied to the machine in the first place, which means you are complicating matters by *not* breaking this directory full of stuff into independent packages. For example, why is NumPy part of this, rather than being a separate requirement to install appropriately on each machine?)

Comment: @chepner we got this as a "SDK" for unique piece of expensive hardware. Some SDK's functionality needs the HW, some doesn't. The whole "SDK" bundles a lot of libraries and some SDK's functionality needs these bundled libraries (mostly old and/or obsolete), and some doesn't. On my notebook, I can import some things and some I can't and I can run some things (from the SDK) and some I can't. It's not nice, but we have to use it because it is the only way to use that hardware in final embedded application. Wraping it in installable package doesn't really help much.

Comment: Another point: `mypy` doesn't actually need to import the module; it just needs access to the module's type hints, which you can supply via a pyi file if the SDK itself doesn't provide type hints.

Comment: (I.e, if `foo.py` is not available, but `foo.pyi` is, then `import foo` will "work" for `mypy` even if it fails at runtime.)

Comment: @chepner thanks for keeping up with me :) - `pyi` seems theoretically possible, but it would still mean modifying the SDK's code (i.e. adding to it). It's not a bad idea, just not very practical - not only is there the burden of keeping it up to date with updates of SDK, there's also a possibility of breaking some HW related functionality (which I can't test from my notebook). I'd like to keep any "hacks" in the code which uses the SDK, not in the SDK itself. Basicaly I don't want to touch the SDK. Btw, so far I just made "Dummy" types all aliases to `Any`, which sort of works. Thanks again.

Comment: You can keep the pyi file with your code, as it should only be necessary when you want to run `mypy` (which I assume will not be on the specialty hardware). I would imagine you need to update your code as often as the pyi file would need to be updated in the event of an SDK change.